# Writing Spark Structured Streaming Output to a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple structured streaming application that just reads data from one Kafka topic and writes to another.

```java
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("test");

SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .config(conf)
        .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "start")
        .load();

StreamingQuery query = dataset
        .writeStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
        .option("topic", "end")
        .start();

query.awaitTermination(20000);
```

There are two messages to be processed on the topic `start`. This code runs without exception, however no messages ever end up on the topic `end`. What is wrong with this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the messages were already on the stream and the starting offset was not set to "earliest".

```java
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", start.getTopicName())
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load();
```